# Offline SpeechRecognizer on Android is not working

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, offline

I am working with SpeechRecognizer. The problem was if there is no active internet connection SpeechRecognizer will throw error `SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK` or `SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER`.

This is my RecognizerIntent

```
    final Intent recognizerIntent;
    recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en");
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);

    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE, true);
```

And I put `recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE, true);`

But no luck. again it will throw the same error.

And I got these 2 errors frequently.

1. `SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY`
2. `SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH`

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to make sure if you have offline package of language you put to EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE installed on the device.

To enable Offline Speech input in supported devices, follow below steps:

- Go to Settings
- Click on “Language and input”
- On-screen keyboard
- Select Google voice typing
- Select Offline speech recognition
- Install desired language

If it still does not work offline, try to change your `EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE` value to something more specific, `"en-US"` for example (That did the trick for me)

And also, if you want to tell `SpeechRecognizer` wich language it should recognize, I guess you should use `EXTRA_LANGUAGE` parameter instead of `EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE`

Hope it will help